# Replace Undercase and Capitlize first letter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string

i have a column that contain string like this :

```
+-------------------+
|       type        |
+-------------------+
|cashback_percentage|
|   cashback_fix    |
|        fix        |
+-------------------+
```

and the query i use:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(replace(type, " ", "_"), 1))) as new_type from mytable;
```

but i got the result like this:

```
+-------------------+
|      new_type     |
+-------------------+
|         C         |
|         C         |
|         F         |
+-------------------+
```

i want the result to remove the underscore and replace it with space, and capitalize each first letter on every word, like this:

```
+-------------------+
|     new_type      |
+-------------------+
|Cashback Percentage|
|   Cashback Fix    |
|        Fix        |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  This approach is to do the concatenation first, to uppercase the first letter, then do a replacement on that entire string to swap underscore with space.

```
SELECT
    type,
    REPLACE(CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(type, 1)), SUBSTRING(type, 2)), '_', ' ') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Replace`

```
select replace(type, '_', ' ') from tb
```

for capitalization you can use Custom function

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))   
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)  
DETERMINISTIC    
BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
END;
```

usage

```
select CAP_FIRST(replace(type, '_', ' ')) from tb
```

[Working Fiddler](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8zvpvHyHkahG3fMjNpTQb1/0)